# InAppBilling V3 what is SKU(Item ID) to make application live?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have creating inallbilling sample code.For testing purpose I have passed SKU="android.test.purchases" but now I want to publish my app on google play store so what should I pass inplace of "android.test.purchase".My application package name or Item Id which user is going to buy from application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that you have to first create product on Google market with the product Id (SKU). To create product you have to create marchents account on the google market. after that you can add that product id into your code. Upload your apk on market then after creating marchents account you can see the Inapp product option under you newly uploaded application. click on it and create product . Let me know if you face any problem.

**EDIT:**

check this link to publish your application on google market

[link1](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/android/how-to-publish-android-apps-in-to-an-android-market.html)

And this link for guidelines to create Inapp product

[link2](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1072599?hl=en)

Comment: How to place product Id of new Product  that is uploaded on Google Play Store into the app , as the .apk is already published?

Comment: I mean, I have published .apk. Now I upload new product, for which I'll have SKU[Product Id]. How can I use that id inside my app, as the app is already uploaded? If I upload new Product, means I need to publish new .apk with that product Id?

Comment: @AnishMittal, I think you need to use it inside your app then re-upload it. That's how I did it, I don't know of any other way to do it, but I'd be very happy if you or someone could provide a different approach.

Comment: @AnishMittal If you are using your own apis than it is very easy to do. Just update or add sku in server and call the api to get all the sku available for all products. While calling inapp billing just pass sku downloaded from server and you can buy the product. Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: how can i test InAppBilling in developing mode with real product i have to create product in play account but i cant be get product from my account its compulsory to app is live for test InAppBilling